# Paho doesn't subscribe to earlier topic on reconnect

Tags: mqtt, paho

Everytime I connect using JS paho client with the same client id, It is not subscribing to the topics that I had subscribed earlier.

```
mqttClient = new Paho.MQTT.Client(constants.MQTT_HOST, Number(constants.MQTT_PORT), '/ws', "User-" + this.getCurrentUserDetails().id);
```

Comment: What options are you passing to the `mqttClient.connect()` call?

Comment: apart of this i am not passing any extra parameter

Answer (score 1):

The [mqttClient.connect()](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/jsdoc/symbols/Paho.MQTT.Client.html#connect) method takes an `options` object which includes the `cleanSession` flag, the default value for this field is `true`.

When `cleanSession` is set to `true` then all existing subscriptions and any queued messages are cleared when the new connection is formed. If you want persistent subscriptions then you will need to set this to false.

For more details, HiveMQ have a nice blog post about sessions [here](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-7-persistent-session-queuing-messages)

Comment: I have set it to false but still its the same. i am using rabbitmq